# How to reflect dynamic method name of an object in Golang

Tags: reflection, go

example

```
router.Get(path, handler) // works fine

methodStr = "Get"    
router.methodStr(path, handler) // error

funcs := map[string]func(){"methodStr": "Get"}
router.funcs["methodStr"](path, handler) // error

reflect.ValueOf(router).MethodByName("Get").Call([]reflect.Value{}) // error
```

I am getting method names as strings. How to call the router object methods with string names

Comment: Most of this isn't valid Go, and you're not supplying any arguments to the reflect example.

Comment: @JimB I have two arguments 1.string value 2. handler function. I'm stuck passing two different arguments in Call method

Comment: You should start by asking yourself why you are doing this, because since I've started Go I never ever used reflection that way. In most case, you shouldn't even need reflection at all…

Comment: @Elwinar hey inform golang developers I am not using refelect so deprecate the feature. fingers crossed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two errors you have aren't valid Go, so I'm not sure what you would expect from them. The last example with reflect doesn't have any arguments for a function that requires 2, which will panic. Adding the 2 arguments works fine:

http://play.golang.org/p/mSziWdW0hn

```
args := []reflect.Value{
    reflect.ValueOf("path"),
    reflect.ValueOf("handler"),
}
reflect.ValueOf(router).MethodByName("Get").Call(args)
```